# Ratio Test Question

Tags: real-analysis

A problem from my analysis text.

Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with $a_n\neq 0$, the Ratio Test states that if $(a_n)$ satisfies
$$
\lim\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=r<1,
$$
then the series converges absolutely.

The problem from Abbott's analysis is

1. Let $r'$ satisfy $r<r'<1$. Explain why there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_{n+1}|\leq|a_n|r'$.
2. Why does $|a_N|\sum(r')^n$ converge?
3. Now, show that $\sum |a_n|$ converges, and conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges.

I've done 1 & 2 but don't know how to arrive at 3. I've tried using 1 and 2 with the comparison test, but I am very lost.

Comment: Your idea is right: where are you stuck?

Comment: Finding upper bound of $\sum |a_n|$ that look like the sequence from (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_1^\infty |a_n| = \left( \sum_1^{N-1} |a_n| \right) + |a_N| + |a_{N+1}| + \dots$

Now, from part 1, conclude that $|a_{N+k}| \le |a_N| \cdot (r')^k$

You end up with the inequality

$\sum_1^\infty |a_n| \le \left( \sum_1^{N-1} |a_n| \right) + |a_N| \sum_1^\infty (r')^k$, and part 2 yields the result for $\{ |a_n| \}_{n \ge 1}$

Lastly, absolute convergence implies convergence - see https://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/1372absconv.pdf